# Tensorflow - How to split batches between GPUs for predicting on trained models?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using models I didn't create but modified (from this repo https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Semantic-Segmentation-Suite)

I have trained models and can use them to predict well enough but I want to run entire folders of images through and split the work between multiple gpus. I don't fully understand how tf.device() works and what I have tried didnt work at all.

I assumed I could do something like so:

```
for i, d in enumerate(['\gpu:0', '\gpu:1']):
    with tf.device(d):
        output = sess.run(network, feed_dict={net_input: image_batch[i]})
```

But this doesnt actually allocate the tasks to the different GPUs, it doesn't raise an error either.

My question is, is it possible to allocate the different images to different instances of the session on seperate GPUs without explicitly modifying the network code pre train. I would like to avoid running two different python scripts with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = ...

Is there a simple way to do this?

From what I understand the definitions of the operations have to be nested in a "with tf.device()" block, however when inferencing the operation is just the loading of the model and weights but if I put that in a "with tf.device()" block I get an error saying the graph already exists and cannot be defined twice.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.device` only applies when building the graph, not executing it, so wrapping `session.run` calls in a device context does nothing.

Instead I recommend you use [tf replicator](https://deepmind.com/blog/tf-replicator-distributed-machine-learning/) or tf distribution strategy (tf.distribute / tf.contrib.distribute depending on the tf version), specifically the MirroredStrategy.